Namespace Managed Package unable to access standard object in the org it is installed in
I have built a Managed Package (with a Namespace) which is setting up a Scheduled Batch Job from a post-installation script in the org it is installed in.
Once the postinstall script is executed, the Scheduled Batch Job is set up in the org. Once the Scheduled Batch job is being executed, it starts by querying (SOQL) for the Account.Name field (pulling all account names currently created in the org).
The issue:
If the Schedulable class is set up as "without sharing" and the SQOL query does not include "WITH SECURITY ENFORCED", the Schedule Batch job executes perfectly. If I however set the Schedulable class to "with sharing" and add the "WITH SECURITY ENFORCED", the Schedulable Batch Job fails and the error return is "sObject Account is not supported".
The Schedulable Batch job is being executed as some kind of "Package user" which does not have access to Standard Objects from the org the Managed Package is installed in.
As you all know, we cannot set a class with "without sharing" as this would fail the Salesforce Security review.
Question: how can I give permission to my managed package to query the Account.Name field of the org it is installed in without setting up the Schedulable class to "without sharing"?
I have tried:

setting up the Schedulable class as "without sharing" and did not "enforce" SOQL security rules. It works but this is making my class not secured.
added the Account.Name field to my package as a custom object (added to the package using the manifest). It did not work; the job failed as it could not access the Account object
tried to import all Profiles with all permissions to the Package, hoping that one of them would cover the Package user". It did not work either.

